# Using INCLUDES multiple times in a SOQL query

Tags: soql, query, include

So my system builds the query for me based on the check boxes selected by the user and I'm using the INCLUDES operator so that multi-select fields can return true if the value is present. I'm having problems when I try to add another INCLUDES condition to the query for a different filter category.
My SOQL query is:

```
select Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate, Type, Business_Unit__c from campaign where IsActive = true AND Business_Unit__c INCLUDES ('Large') AND Region__c INCLUDES ('EMEA') order by StartDate desc limit 20
```

What am I missing here? Can you only use INCLUDES once in a query?

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?  You can use multiple `INCLUDES` operator in one soql query.

Comment: I just realised that I was trying to use INCLUDES on a drop down field as apposed to a multi-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use INCLUDES multiple times within a single query but the query operator has to match the type of data is it trying to access. By this I mean that INCLUDES is for searching through multi-select fields where the data is represented as a single string separated by semi-colons i.e. ('Large;Medium;Small'). 
The reason you can't use = here is because the query string would have to exactly equals the string stored in the record.

**INCLUDES** - for querying Multi-Select fields

**=** - for querying Text fields, Dropdown fields, and other fields where the user can only select a single value.

Comment: hunty.. Is it an answer?

Comment: Yeah, basically I was using the INCLUDES operator on a field that wasn't multi-select.

Answer (score 1):

Try something liek this:

```
Select id, leadSource from lead where leadsource in ('Dreamforce') and status in ('Open - Not Contacted') limit 100
```

So, the point is instead of include use IN

Your query should be like:

```
select Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate, Type, Business_Unit__c from campaign where IsActive = true AND Business_Unit__c IN('Large') AND Region__c IN ('EMEA') order by StartDate desc limit 20
```

Comment: The problem with this is that when the Business_Unit__c or the Region__c field in the database contains more than one value. e.g. Region__c could contain 'EMEA;AMER'

Comment: you can use many values in IN clause i.e. **name IN ('abc', 'pqr')**

Comment: I was looking to use multiple clauses i.e. field1 IN ('value1', 'value2') AND field2 IN ('value3', 'value4'). My problem was that I was trying to use INCLUDES on a field that wasn't a multi-select. I need to use = for this field and INCLUDES for the others.